Бинарный поиск. Переполнение памяти и большое время выполнения программы
Дано два списка чисел, числа в первом списке упорядочены по неубыванию. Для каждого числа из второго списка определите номер первого и последнего появления этого числа в первом списке.
Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных записано два числа N
и M
(1≤N,M≤20000
). Во второй строке записано N
упорядоченных по неубыванию целых чисел — элементы первого списка. В третьей строке записаны M
целых неотрицательных чисел - элементы второго списка. Все числа в списках - целые 32-битные знаковые.
Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести M
строчек. Для каждого числа из второго списка нужно вывести номер его первого и последнего вхождения в первый список. Нумерация начинается с единицы. Если число не входит в первый список, нужно вывести одно число 0
.
Примеры
Входные данные
10 5
1 1 3 3 5 7 9 18 18 57
57 3 9 1 179

Выходные данные
10 10
3 4
7 7
1 2
0

def binarnui_poisk (a,value):
    low = 0
    high = len(a) - 1
    mid = len(a) // 2

    while a[mid] != value and low <= high:
        if value > a[mid]:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
        mid = (low + high) // 2


    if a[mid] != a[-1] and a.count(value) == 2:
        if a[mid] == a[mid + 1] == value:
            return mid+1,mid + 2

    elif a[mid] == a[mid - 1] == value:
        return mid, mid + 1
    elif  a[mid] == value:
        return mid+1,mid+1
    else:
        return 0


N, K = map(int, input().split())
sp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
sp1_ = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(K):
    k = binarnui_poisk(sp,sp1_[i])
    if k == 0:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(*k) 


Из-за count() получается линейный алгоритм, а нужен логарифмический, поэтому не проходит.

Правильность: код ответит неправильно если в первом списке три или более одинаковых значений. Просто нет такого return для трёх значений.

Скорость: a.count(value) == 2 - эта операция требует просмотреть весь список. Она превращает сложность алгоритма в линейную вместо логарифма.

В википедии есть реализация бинарного поиска для первого и последнего из серии одинаковых элементов. Однако в питоне имеется и штатный модуль bisect с нужными процедурами

@stanislav-volodarskiy а, если  a.count(value) == 1 или 0, он тоже ведь список просматривает?

он тоже ведь список просматривает? да - а как иначе посчитать, если нет другой информации, кроме как пройти весь список?

@MBo  я тогда попытаюсь переделать завтра и скину исправленный код и куда скидывать переделанный код?

Вопрос отредактируете (<править>)

@MBo что не так с вопросом?

@user27630724 Это я подсказал "куда скидывать переделанный код"

@stanislav-volodarskiy. Я исправил код, тесты проходит по времени и по памяти, спасибо за помощь (разъяснение на счет count() и линейной сложности)

@MBo. Я исправил код, тесты проходит по времени и по памяти, спасибо за помощь (разъяснение на счет count() и линейной сложности)

У вас сейчас код работает так, как вы ожидаете? Если да, то правку надо откатить, поскольку с помощью неё вы решили свою проблему. Либо удалите вопрос, либо откатите вопрос к предыдущей версии и добавьте ответ, который решил вашу проблему.

@Chaos_Sower исправил код

Была проблема а том что выполнялся линейный алгоритм, а надо было логарифмический, для того чтобы выполнялся логарифмический я использовал бинарный поиск, также я убрал метод  count (), который из логарифмического делал линейный алгоритм
'''Код отредактированный'''

def left_binarnui_poisk (a,value): # левый бинарный поиск
    result = -1
    low = 0
    high = len(a) - 1
    mid = len(a) // 2

    while low <= high:
        if value == a[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
            result = mid + 1
        elif value > a[mid]:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1

        mid = (low + high) // 2
    return result


def right_binarnui_poisk (a,value): # правый бинарный поиск
    result = -1
    low = 0
    high = len(a) - 1
    mid = len(a) // 2

    while low <= high:
        if value == a[mid]:
            low = mid + 1
            result = mid + 1
        elif value > a[mid]:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1

        mid = (low + high) // 2
    return result



#ввод данных
N, K = map(int, input().split())
sp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
sp1_ = [int(i) for i in input().split()]


# организация вывода
for i in range(K):
    result_itog = [left_binarnui_poisk(sp,sp1_[i]),right_binarnui_poisk(sp,sp1_[i])]
    if result_itog.count(-1): # если вывод равен [-1,-1], то выведет 0 по условию задачи
        print(0)
    else:
        print(*result_itog)


это ответ на вопрос?

@aleksandr barakin да это ответ на вопрос, а вы модератор ?

добавь описание в чем была проблема, и как ты ее исправил.

@Grundy я исправил описание

Мне не нравится ответ автора вопроса. Не потому что он не правильный. Я его не тестировал, очевидных ошибок я нём не вижу. Мне он не нравится потому что использует странный дизайн: переменная result, две проверки условия на цикл, отсутствие утверждений об инвариантах.
Мой вариант всегда возвращает позицию i для вставки элемента v в упорядоченный список a, такую что a[:i] + [v] + a[i:] сохраняет порядок. Если в списке a есть одна или несколько таких позиций, bisect_left возвращает минимальный такой индекс - самую левую позицию, bisect_right возвращает максимальный индекс - самую правую позицию. Если обе функции вернули одинаковые значения, элемент v в списке отсутствует.
Обе функции нафаршированы закомментированными утверждениями об инвариантах. Закомментированными потому что любое такое утверждение увеличивает время работы функции c log n до n log n.
В каждом цикле делается только одно сравнение. Это увеличивает производительность. Обычно второе условие проверяет равенство для раннего выхода из цикла. Можно показать что эта оптимизация экономит в среднем одну итерацию, увеличивая количество проверок в два раза. То есть, она замедляет поиск.
def bisect_left(a, v):
    low = 0
    high = len(a)
    # assert a[:low] < v <= a[high:]

    while low < high:
        # assert a[:low] < v <= a[high:]
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        assert low <= mid < high
        if a[mid] < v:
            # assert a[:mid + 1] < v
            low = mid + 1
            # assert a[:low] < v
        else:
            # assert v <= a[mid:]
            high = mid
            # assert v <= a[high:]
        # assert a[:low] < v <= a[high:]

    # assert a[:low] < v <= a[high:]
    assert low == high
    return low


def bisect_right(a, v):
    low = 0
    high = len(a)
    # assert a[:low] <= v < a[high:]

    while low < high:
        # assert a[:low] <= v < a[high:]
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        assert low <= mid < high
        if v < a[mid]:
            # assert v < a[mid:]
            high = mid
            # assert v < a[high:]
        else:
            # assert a[:mid + 1] <= v
            low = mid + 1
            # assert a[:low] <= v
        # assert a[:low] <= v < a[high:]

    # assert a[:low] <= v < a[high:]
    assert low == high
    return low


def bisect_range(a, v):
    return bisect_left(a, v), bisect_right(a, v)


def main():
    _, k = map(int, input().split())
    a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    for v in map(int, input().split()):
        left, right = bisect_range(a, v)
        if left == right:
            print(0)
        else:
            print(left + 1, right)


main()

P.S. Это всё сделано для только для упражнения. Функции bisect.bisect_left, bisect.bisect_right есть в стандартной библиотеке.
P.P.S. bisect_left и bisect_right почти одинаковы. Их можно объединить в одну функцию, которая вместо значения v принимает функцию-предикат p. Код сократится. Не знаю можно ли сказать что он станет проще, но отлаживать его будет легче.
def bisect_pred(a, p):
    low = 0
    high = len(a)
    # assert not p(a[:low]) and p(a[high:])

    while low < high:
        # assert not p(a[:low]) and p(a[high:])
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        assert low <= mid < high
        if p(a[mid]):
            # assert p(a[mid:])
            high = mid
            # assert p(a[high:])
        else:
            # assert not p(a[:mid + 1])
            low = mid + 1
            # assert not p(a[:low])
        # assert not p(a[:low]) and p(a[high:])

    # assert not p(a[:low]) and p(a[high:])
    assert low == high
    # assert not p(a[:low]) and p(a[low:])
    return low


def bisect_range(a, v):
    return (
        bisect_pred(a, lambda a_i: a_i >= v),  # bisect_left
        bisect_pred(a, lambda a_i: a_i >  v)   # bisect_right
    )


То есть у тебя левый и правый поиск выполняется одновременно?

@user27630724, нет. Это два отдельных поиска. Их можно объединить до некоторой степени. Но это даст очень маленький выигрыш, а код станет ещё сложнее - добавится ещё одна процедура двоичного поиска.

Так у меня такой же код

@user27630724, верхние уровни у нас похожи, правда. Различия начинаются в самих процедурах двоичного поиска.
